# Avalonia 11 and the Windows 10 on-screen keyboard

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

I'm trying to get the native Windows 10 on-screen keyboard to work with Avalonia 11. There seems to be no documentation about this subject, making me unsure if it's supported at all. I have seen chinese/japanese users using their respective IME, but with no mention on how they got it to open.

I've seen some minor discussions that mention setting `InputMethod.IsInputMethodEnabled`, but that does not seem to have any effect. I've seen others discuss implementing `ITextInputMethodImpl` to implement custom logic. In Avalonia 11 the methods in that interface are all declared internal and marked obsolete.

Focusing a text input field in another application, such as notepad, pops up the OSK without issue.

Is this a supported thing for Avalonia 11 at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue and it is not currently supported.

https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/7732

Comment: Well that's unfortunate...